# Intel MKTME boot/grub problem/issue with Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, boot, encryption, ram

So moments after booting Ubuntu 20, 22, 23 (including applicable Pro editions) from a Dell XPS running 32 Gb of LPDDR5 and a Intel VPRO 1280p, the top right corner flashes and only this dialog with the the following “error”.

```
kernel: x86/mktme: No known encryption algorithm is supported: 0x4
```

The problem consists only on Ubuntu with and with out FDE. I do have a 1Tb SED and was wondering if that could be a problem but I removed that from the probability because Fedora does not give me any problem besides overheating with and without every power and thermal install

I’ve googled and googled this issue and there are known issue’s with Kubuntu.

Is this a security bug before/during GRUB; or is there a known kernel fix around this or an install/update that would fix this?

Comment: This was helpful in understanding a little more: https://forums.anandtech.com/threads/what-are-the-requirements-for-intel%C2%AE-total-memory-encryption-on-13900k.2611844/